# Converting 10 bit Y'CbCr to 8 bit RGB using vImageConvert_YpCbCrToARGB_GenerateConversion on iOS

Tags: ios, image-processing, avfoundation, accelerate-framework, cvpixelbuffer

Given a `CVPixelBuffer` with format `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr10BiPlanarVideoRange`, I'm trying to generate a corresponding 8-bit RGB frame for further processing. I understand this will be a lossy conversion – the RGB frame will just be used to calculate some descriptive statistics.

I'm basing my conversion on [this sample code provided in the Accelerate documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vimage/converting_luminance_and_chrominance_planes_to_an_argb_image?language=objc), which shows how to convert 8-bit BT.601 color samples to RGB.

The core of what I'm trying to do revolves around the `vImageConvert_YpCbCrToARGB_GenerateConversion` function, which allows you to specify a color conversion matrix, pixel range information, input YpCbCr format, and output ARGB format (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1533189-vimageconvert_ypcbcrtoargb_gener)). So far, I've adapted the sample code in the following ways:

1. I have changed the color conversion matrix. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a built-in constant like `kvImage_YpCbCrToARGBMatrix_ITU_R_601_4` for BT.2020. Instead, I've created my own based on the specification:

```
var colorMatrix = vImage_YpCbCrToARGBMatrix(
            Yp: 1,
            Cr_R: 1.4746,
            Cr_G: -0.5714,
            Cb_G: -0.16455,
            Cb_B: 1.8814
        )
```

2. I have updated the `vImage_YpCbCrPixelRange` to (hopefully) account for the 10 bit format:

```
var pixelRange = vImage_YpCbCrPixelRange(Yp_bias: 64,
                                                 CbCr_bias: 512,
                                                 YpRangeMax: 940,
                                                 CbCrRangeMax: 960,
                                                 YpMax: 255,
                                                 YpMin: 0,
                                                 CbCrMax: 255,
                                                 CbCrMin: 0)
```

I am not confident about `YpMax`, `YpMin`, `CbCrMax`, or `CbCrMin`, but the other values should be correct based on the documentation's description of the 10-bit video range format (`kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr10BiPlanarVideoRange`).

3. The core adjustment/problem (or so I believe): I am trying to change the `inYpCbCrType` to reflect the actual format of my `CVPixelBuffer`. The sample code uses `kvImage422CbYpCrYp8`, but I assume I'm looking for something like `kvImage420CbYpCrYp10` (which doesn't exist). As far as I can tell, the only options are listed [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vimageypcbcrtype). I have tried some of the 10 bit formats (4:2:2 and 4:4:4), but the results are pretty wonky (grainy with gaps and mostly yellow). Of course, that's probably expected since I'm specifying a random chroma subsampling ratio, not the actual 4:2:0 used in my pixel buffer.

I believe what I'm trying to do is possible; at least, the attached table in the documentation for `vImageConvert_YpCbCrToARGB_GenerateConversion` indicates that YUV10 to RGB8 is supported (though it doesn't say for which chroma subsampling ratios).

[image: Table showing supported conversions]

With that background out of the way, my core questions are as follows:

- Is what I'm trying to do supported?
- If so, which `vImageYpCbCrType` am I supposed to use?
- If that's the wrong question, what workflow should I be using instead?

I am relatively new to image processing (I mostly deal with audio signal processing), so please let me know if I have any fundamental misunderstandings in addition to the described issues. Thanks!

Comment: Hey - did you figure this out? Not sure what the correct range values are for 10-bit YUV

Comment: @mrousavy I ended up writing my own Metal shaders to accomplish this. I can confirm that, for 10-bit video range YCbCr formats, the Y channel goes from 64 to 940 and the Cb/Cr channels goes from 64 to 960.